Flutter: Updating a specific widget in a ListView using Notifier
I'm working on a To-Do type app that:

Let's the user create events, with a given timing during the day
Sends notifications (using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) when an event is nearing its end; the notification includes an action that the user can tap, and it updates the related event (e.g., completing it, extending it).
If the app is in focus, I want to ensure that the particular event in the list gets updated, and I believe I will need to use Notifier/Consumer - that part may not be correct.

What I can't figure out is how I can do that (Notification action 'Mark as complete' > Updates event (DB model) > Notify listeners > Only a single widget in the tree updating, without rebuilding the whole list.
What I have:

A model (sqflite) for an event
A DB Helper class for that event
A list of widgets to update, which would be at the location of Text in the extract below.

I've tried to create a simplified screen to test it out, but I'm sort of stuck.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
    children: [
      ListView.builder(

        // I would be listening here, on `Text` for a change,
        // and aiming to update only the event updated
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => **Text**(events[index].toString()), 
        itemCount: events.length,

      ),

      // Using a button to simulate an 'external' update of the event
      MaterialButton(onPressed: () {
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

          // The updating of the event here would simulate an external update,
          // calling notifyListeners to get the selected event to update. Obviously
          // I don't want to use setState here, as it's not the point.
          events[i].completed = !events[i].completed;
        }
      })
    ],
  ));
}

So my questions are:

Should the Event model be a ChangeNotifier, of the DB Helper (EventProvider)?
Can this be done (single widget listening to change notifications and only that one updating)?
If it can be done, how? Notifier/Consumer/Provider, and also how to make it conditional, i.e. 'Listen to changes but only do anything if the event updated is the same as the event you're displaying as a widget (in this case the Text widget above)?

I could just refresh the whole list, but I want to understand if I could refresh a single item.
Thank you so much!
